# Python mutithreadding, diffrent execution timings

Tags: python, multithreading, timing

HI I have made a python code to check its multi threading capabilities of the code
here is my code

```
import os
import time
import threading
count = 0
number_of_itration =10000000

 
 
def print_square(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    begin = time.time()
    print(f"T1Begin Time is {begin} Seconds\n")
    for i in range(number_of_itration):
        format(num * num * num)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"T1End Time is {end} Seconds\n")
    print(f"T1Total runtime of the program is {end - begin} Seconds\n")

def print_square1(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    begin = time.time()
    print(f"T2Begin Time is {begin} Seconds\n")
    for i in range(number_of_itration):
        format(num * num * num)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"T2End Time is {end} Seconds\n")
    print(f"T2Total runtime of the program is {end - begin} Seconds\n")

def print_square2(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    begin = time.time()
    print(f"T3Begin Time is {begin} Seconds\n")
    for i in range(number_of_itration):
        format(num * num * num)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"T3End Time is {end} Seconds\n")
    print(f"T3Total runtime of the program is {end - begin} Seconds\n")    

def print_square3(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    begin = time.time()
    print(f"T4Begin Time is {begin} Seconds\n")
    for i in range(number_of_itration):
        format(num * num * num)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"T4End Time is {end} Seconds\n")
    print(f"T4Total runtime of the program is {end - begin} Seconds\n") 

def print_square4(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    begin = time.time()
    print(f"T5Begin Time is {begin} Seconds\n")
    for i in range(number_of_itration):
        format(num * num * num)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"T5End Time is {end} Seconds\n")
    print(f"T5Total runtime of the program is {end - begin} Seconds\n")

def print_square5(num):
    # function to print square of given num
    begin = time.time()
    print(f"T6Begin Time is {begin} Seconds\n")
    for i in range(number_of_itration):
        format(num * num * num)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"T6End Time is {end} Seconds\n")
    print(f"T6Total runtime of the program is {end - begin} Seconds\n")



t1 = threading.Thread(target=print_square, args=(10,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=print_square1, args=(10,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=print_square2, args=(10,))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=print_square3, args=(10,))
t5 = threading.Thread(target=print_square4, args=(10,))
t6 = threading.Thread(target=print_square5, args=(10,))


# starting thread 1
t1.start()
# starting thread 2
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t5.start()
t6.start()
```

here Though im calling the same function, with same process, im getting different execution speeds why does it behave like this?

the console print is displayed below

```
T1Begin Time is 1660808471.2426443 Seconds

T2Begin Time is 1660808471.256599 Seconds
T3Begin Time is 1660808471.256599 Seconds


T4Begin Time is 1660808471.6522112 Seconds

T5Begin Time is 1660808472.0985467 Seconds

T6Begin Time is 1660808472.6798558 Seconds

T2End Time is 1660808478.985982 Seconds

T2Total runtime of the program is 7.7293829917907715 Seconds

T1End Time is 1660808480.8472064 Seconds

T1Total runtime of the program is 9.604562044143677 Seconds

T5End Time is 1660808481.6313431 Seconds

T5Total runtime of the program is 9.532796382904053 Seconds

T3End Time is 1660808482.2941368 Seconds
T6End Time is 1660808482.3155725 Seconds

T6Total runtime of the program is 9.635716676712036 Seconds


T3Total runtime of the program is 11.037537813186646 Seconds

T4End Time is 1660808482.4218156 Seconds

T4Total runtime of the program is 10.769604444503784 Seconds
```

I would like to know if its expected or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is unsurprising*. Your program is using one CPU core and you are adding more and more work for the one core as you call `.start()` on your threads. So you would expect later threads to have some more competition for CPU resources.

* I wouldn't say "expected" purely because performance measurements are hard and lots of unexpected things do crop up.

Comment: Is there any what i can start different threads in different cores with python? or how can i utilize python to automatically distribute resource within cores ?

Comment: If you want to use more than one core, you are looking for `multiprocessing`